# Show alert dialog when closing browser tab (using beforeunload)

Tags: onbeforeunload

I am looking to show an alert box when closing the browser tab.

I did look through several examples, but I am unable to get it working. Sharing my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/alert-on-close-fhl-1-vqjggc?file=/src/App.tsx).

It generates a link to a tab where the application can be opened in its own page such as https://vqjggc.csb.app/

When closing the tab using the X button or `Ctrl+w`, my expectation was that it would show a dialog, but it doesn't seem to.

Please advise what I am doing wrong.
I have tried on both Chrome (Version 116.0.5845.141 (Official Build) (64-bit)) as well as Edge (Version 116.0.1938.69 (Official build) (64-bit))

Attached a gif of what I observe when opening the app using the above link and hitting `Ctrl+w`.[image]

Answer (score 0):

When the component unmounts, the cleanup function will be executed. In this case, the cleanup function removes the event listener for the "beforeunload" event.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleBeforeUnload = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.returnValue = "";
    };
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", handleBeforeUnload);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", handleBeforeUnload);
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: @yassine-eluharni, thanks for the response! Hm, I actually do not see much of a visual difference by trying out your snippet above (unless my expectation is not correct). I tried closing the page immediately after visiting it, and it closes without the alert dialog. If I, click somewhere on the page, however, it does the show the dialog, both with my original implementation as well as with your snippet. 
Is there a way to show the dialog on closing the page immediately upon visiting it? Or does that not serve a purpose?